# Where to find a 1983 NTSB report of a R-22 clutch failure?

Tags: helicopter, incidents, ntsb

Why can't I find the incident report I had to file after my death defying landing at John Wayne Airport in Costa Mesa Ca. around 1983?
They found the clutch with 4 belts to have malfunctioned and grounded all Robinsons in service, until a better configuration was developed.

Comment: Where have you looked? The report is probably not digitized you may have to request a copy from the NTSB.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you'll have to poke the Records Management folks at the NTSB when they get back in on Tuesday :) See if you can get as much detail as you can in the meantime -- the incident report form is also called a 6120.1 if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I Have looked through NTSB , also through some FAA links..

Comment: Not the incident you refer to, but an interesting review of more recent R22 clutch belt failures is found in this [Australian report](https://www.atsb.gov.au/media/4120236/ai-2009-038_final.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your "death-defying experience" was classified as an incident or accident. [Checking the list of occurrences the NTSB classifies as an incident does not show that what happened to you needs to be reported as one.](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=36418957aeb9385b90ae9a44f4a8d1cd&mc=true&node=pt49.7.830&rgn=div5#se49.7.830_15) Mechanical failures of all kinds happen on aircraft all the time. Very few of them are required to be reported to the NTSB.

Comment: Well they grounded all Robinsons Worldwide and went from the 4 belt setup to 1. In my case 3 had broken and wrapped around the main shaft of the rotor, and the clutch was still stretching the last 1. So honestly I don't know how it was reported. Death defying probably not.tons of smoke ,yes,. Just happy to be here.

Comment: Mechanical issue, likely reported to the FAA and to the manufacturer, but not to the NTSB. Good outcome. :)

Comment: Thanks. Mostly luck the ground was there at the right time. Frank Robinson came out to view it himself, and I may have pictures somewhere.